# Backbone router not dispatched?

Tags: backbone.js, router

I'm new in backbone 0.9.1.
I found when I change hash and I can not trigger hash change in my demo.
My URL is http://[...]/backbone/#help. I think I should receive a alert message "help", but I'm not.

```
$(function() {
    var App = {
        Controllers:{},
        initialize: function(){
            new App.Controllers.Routes();
            var h = new Backbone.History();
            h.start({root: '/backbone/'});
        }
    };

    App.Controllers.Routes = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "help":                 "help",
            "search/:query":        "search",
        },

        help: function() {
            alert("help");
        },

        search: function(query) {
            alert("search");
        }
    });

    App.initialize();
});
```

Is there some misunderstanding or misuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate a History object yourself. Also, if you're not using pushstate, you don't need to specify the `root` in the start options.

So, your initialize method should look like this:

```
        initialize: function(){
            new App.Controllers.Routes();
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
```

Comment: thx for your help~
but seems in Backbone 0.9.1 there is not a history in Backbone's prototype, when I call Backbone.history.start(); an error message received: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'start' of undefined。
looks like router has some change in 0.9.1?

Comment: that's not a change in 0.9.x and the .history attribute has never been part of the Backbone object's prototype. The Backbone.history attribute is automatically added after you instantiate a router with routes defined on it. If you're getting this error, it means your router is not instantiated or is not configured correctly.

Comment: change initialize function to
new App.Controllers.Routes();
Backbone.history.start();

problem resolved.